# What is the fastest way to persistently increment a list of numbers from multiple threads?

Tags: c#, multithreading

My application has different tasks each one posting an XML Document through each HTTP POST on a different endpoint. For every thread I need to keep count of the message I sent, which is identified by a unique incremental number.

I need a mechanism that, after a message has been received by the endpoint will save the last message id sent, so that if there is a problem and the application needs to restart it won't send the same message again, and will restart from where it currently was.

If I don't persist the counters, on my laptop I can manage to obtain a throughput of about 100 messages processed per second for every queue with 5 tasks running. My goal is to achieve no more than a 10/15% reduction in throughput by persisting the counters.

Using SQL Server for saving the counters, with a row for every tasks gives me a 50% decrease in throughput. Saving the counter value on a text file for every task is a bit faster but still far from my goal. I am looking for a way to persist such information so that I can be as close as possible to my goal. I thought that maybe appending the last processed Id rather than updating it could help me in avoiding possible write locks, but the bottom line is that I don't care if for the sake of performance I will have to waste disk space or have a higher startup time for reading the last counter.

In your experience what might be a fast way to avoid contentions and safely persist data from multiple tasks even at the cost of more disk space?

Comment: What does multithreading have to do with this? I don't get the impression you want any thread to talk to any other thread.

Comment: "...but both the solutions aren't very satisfying." Why is that?

Comment: Your question is too broad in it's current form.  Show us the code you've written so far, and tell us more about the use case.

Comment: Do you want the threads to persist the current state (i.e. all the intermediate calculations), or do you just want the thread to save a single number that tells how far it's gone through the calculation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get pretty good performance with an ESENT storage, via the [ManagedEsent - PersistentDictionary](http://managedesent.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=PersistentDictionaryDocumentation) wrapper.

The `PersistentDictionary` class is concurrent and provides real concurrent access to the ESENT backend. You would represent everything in key-value pair format.

Give it a try, it is not much code to write.

ESENT is an in-process database engine, disk based + in-memory caching, used throughout several Windows components (Search, Exchange, etc). It does provide transactional support, which is what you're after.

It has been **included in all versions of Windows since 2000** so you don't need to install any dependencies other than ManagedEsent.

You would probably want to define something like this:

```
var dictionary = new PersistentDictionary<Guid, int>("ThreadStorage");
```

The key, I assume, should be something unique (maybe even the service endpoint) so that you are able to re-map it after a restart. The value is the last message identifier.

I am pasting below, shamelessly, their performance benchmarks:

- Sequential inserts  **32,000 entries/second**
- Random inserts  **17,000 entries/second**
- Random Updates  **36,000 entries/second**
- Random lookups (database cached in memory)  **137,000 entries/second**
- Linq queries (range of records) **14,000 queries/second**

You fit in the **Random Updates** case, which as you can see offers a really good throughput.

Comment: I tried this and it is definitely what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue as OP asked.
I used SQL server Sequence Numbers (with CREATE SEQUENCE).
However, the accepted answer is a good solution to avoid using SQL server.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).